# Set cmake project description with commit id

Tags: git, cmake

I just learned how I can use

```
project(ProjectName VERSION 1.0)
```

and the [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) to play with the version and embed it into the binary.

On [project documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) I see it also accept a description string.

```
project(ProjectName VERSION 1.0 description_string)
```

So I want to use the commit id as the description string. I can read commit id from command line with `git rev-parse HEAD` but how can I use that to set the description?

Comment: Just run `git rev-parse HEAD` via [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html), store its output in the variable via OUTPUT_VARIABLE option and use that variable in the `project()` call. For strip terminating newline symbol in the output, use `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` option.

Comment: Note that if the repository you use has meaningful descriptive annotated tags (as many public projects do and you can emulate this in private ones), you may wish to use `git describe` to get the descriptive string, which can then be something like `v2.17` for a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FindGit](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGit.html) module to find a git executable and then run it with [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) to get the result, so something like this:

```
find_package(Git REQUIRED)
execute_process(COMMAND "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" rev-parse HEAD OUTPUT_VARIABLE COMMIT_ID OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
project(ProjectName VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "${COMMIT_ID}")
```

Comment: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (project):
  project with VERSION, DESCRIPTION or HOMEPAGE_URL must use LANGUAGES before
  language names.`

Comment: @KcFnMi use [`string(TIMESTAMP ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#timestamp) (and separate question next time)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71763399/set-cmake-project-description-with-current-datetime