# Set cmake project description with current datetime

Tags: cmake

I just learned how I can use

```
project(ProjectName VERSION 1.0)
```

and the [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) to play with the version and embed it into the binary.

On [project documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) I see it also accept a description string.

```
project(ProjectName VERSION 1.0 description_string)
```

So I want to use the current datetime at the time cmake is running
as the description string.

Wondering if I can use datetime, not commit datetime but current datetime at the time cmake is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string(TIMESTAMP ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#timestamp) like this:

```
string(TIMESTAMP RUN_TIME)
project(ProjectName VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "${RUN_TIME}")
```

Note, however, that this will be populated only when CMake is actually run on this script. So, for example, you generated your project for, say, Visual Studio and work a few days on it there. If you didn't change the CMake file, remove CMake cache or run cmake on the script any other way your date will be stale.